# How to resolve "Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my Android project I created a buildSrc dir with this build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.4.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44.2")
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1")
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("androidModulePlugin") {
            id = "com.zeyadgasser.gradle.android-module-plugin"
            implementationClass = "com.zeyadgasser.flux.gradle.AndroidModulePlugin"
            displayName = "AndroidModulePlugin"
            description = "Plugin for setting up android modules"
        }
    }
}
```

Running the app I get this error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /Users/zeyadgasser/AndroidStudioProjects/Flux/app/src/main/java/com/zeyadgasser/flux/screens/main/MainUI.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:241)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:236)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.invokeCodegen(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:312)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.runCodegen(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:348)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:485)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:424)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:360)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:HomeScreenContent visibility:public modality:FINAL <> (mviOnClick:kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>, mvvmOnClick:kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>) returnType:kotlin.Unit
  annotations:
    Composable
  VALUE_PARAMETER name:mviOnClick index:0 type:kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>
  VALUE_PARAMETER name:mvvmOnClick index:1 type:kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>
  BLOCK_BODY
    RETURN type=kotlin.Nothing from='public final fun HomeScreenContent (mviOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>, mvvmOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>): kotlin.Unit declared in com.zeyadgasser.flux.screens.main.MainUIKt'
      CALL 'public final fun Column$default (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, verticalArrangement: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical?, horizontalAlignment: androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal?, content: @[Composable] @[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope, kotlin.Unit>, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit [inline] declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
        modifier: CALL 'public final fun padding (paddingValues: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues): androidx.compose.ui.Modifier declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingKt' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier origin=null
          $receiver: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:Companion type:androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion visibility:public [final,static]' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion origin=null
          paddingValues: CALL 'public final fun PaddingValues-0680j_4 (all: androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp): androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingKt' type=androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues origin=null
            all: CALL 'public open fun constructor-impl (value: kotlin.Float): androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp declared in androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp' type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp origin=null
              value: CONST Float type=kotlin.Float value=28.0
        verticalArrangement: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Null type=androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical? value=null
        horizontalAlignment: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Null type=androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal? value=null
        content: BLOCK type=@[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope, kotlin.Unit> origin=LAMBDA
          COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          FUNCTION_REFERENCE 'private final fun HomeScreenContent$lambda$0 ($mviOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>, $mvvmOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>): kotlin.Unit declared in com.zeyadgasser.flux.screens.main.MainUIKt' type=@[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope, kotlin.Unit> origin=INLINE_LAMBDA reflectionTarget=null
            $mviOnClick: GET_VAR 'mviOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit> declared in com.zeyadgasser.flux.screens.main.MainUIKt.HomeScreenContent' type=kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit> origin=null
            $mvvmOnClick: GET_VAR 'mvvmOnClick: kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit> declared in com.zeyadgasser.flux.screens.main.MainUIKt.HomeScreenContent' type=kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit> origin=null
        $mask0: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=6
        $handler: CONST Null type=kotlin.Any? value=null

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate$default(FunctionCodegen.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethodNode(ClassCodegen.kt:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethod(ClassCodegen.kt:425)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.FileCodegen.lower(JvmPhases.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:65)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call: CALL 'public final fun Column$default (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, verticalArrangement: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical?, horizontalAlignment: androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal?, content: @[Composable] @[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope, kotlin.Unit>, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit [inline] declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
Method: null
File is unknown
The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.getMethodNode(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrInlineCodegen.genInlineCall(IrInlineCodegen.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrInlineCallGenerator.genCall(IrInlineCallGenerator.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:522)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrCall.accept(IrCall.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitReturn(ExpressionCodegen.kt:908)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitReturn(ExpressionCodegen.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrReturn.accept(IrReturn.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitStatementContainer(ExpressionCodegen.kt:457)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:461)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBlockBody.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generate(ExpressionCodegen.kt:241)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.doGenerate(FunctionCodegen.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:45)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't find inline method Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnKt;.Column$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement$Vertical;Landroidx/compose/ui/Alignment$Horizontal;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.getMethodNode(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.loadCompiledInlineFunction(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrSourceCompilerForInline.compileInlineFunction(IrSourceCompilerForInline.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:47)
    ... 65 more
```

My plugin sets some default configs for modules including JUnit5. When I apply the plugin to a modules the tests are working fine even though I cannot run the app, due to the exception above. Help please, thanks in advance.

The plugin:

```kotlin
package com.zeyadgasser.flux.gradle

import com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultApiVersion
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.apply
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.configure

class AndroidModulePlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) = with(project) {
        val isAppModule = path.split("/").last() == "app"
        if (isAppModule) {
            plugins.apply("com.android.application")
        } else {
            plugins.apply("com.android.library")
        }
        plugins.apply("kotlin-android")
        plugins.apply("kotlin-parcelize")
        plugins.apply("kotlin-kapt")
        plugins.apply("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
        apply<TestingPlugin>()
        apply<CoveragePlugin>()
        apply<DetektPlugin>()
        apply<PipelinePlugin>()

        with(android()) {
            compileSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.compileSdkVersion)
            buildToolsVersion(AndroidVersions.buildToolsVersion)
            defaultConfig {
                if (isAppModule) applicationId = AndroidConfig.appId
                minSdkVersion = DefaultApiVersion(AndroidVersions.minSdkVersion)
                targetSdkVersion = DefaultApiVersion(AndroidVersions.targetSdkVersion)
                versionCode = AndroidConfig.versionCode
                versionName = AndroidConfig.versionName
            }
            buildFeatures.compose = true
            composeOptions {
                kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
            }
            buildTypes {
                getByName("debug") {
                    isDebuggable = true
                }
                getByName("release") {
                    isMinifyEnabled = true
                    proguardFiles(
                        getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                    )
                }
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
            testOptions {
                unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
            }
            packagingOptions {
                exclude("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
                exclude("META-INF/NOTICE")
                exclude("META-INF/LICENSE")
            }
        }

        setupIfApplication()
        addDependencies()
    }

    private fun Project.addDependencies() {
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
        dependencies.add("implementation", "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
        hilt()
        navigate()
        compose()
        lifecycle()
    }

    private fun Project.lifecycle() {
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:${DepVersions.lifecycle_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:${DepVersions.lifecycle_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:${DepVersions.lifecycle_version}"
        )
    }

    private fun Project.compose() {
        dependencies.add(
            "debugImplementation",
            "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "debugImplementation",
            "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1")
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:${DepVersions.compose_ui_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.3.1")
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1")
    }

    private fun Project.navigate() {
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:${DepVersions.nav_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:${DepVersions.nav_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:${DepVersions.nav_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:${DepVersions.nav_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:${DepVersions.nav_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add("implementation", "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
    }

    private fun Project.hilt() {
        dependencies.add(
            "implementation",
            "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:${DepVersions.hilt_version}"
        )
        dependencies.add(
            "kapt",
            "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:${DepVersions.hilt_version}"
        )
    }

    private fun Project.setupIfApplication() =
        plugins.withId("com.android.application") { configure<AppExtension> { ensureObfuscations() } }

    private fun AppExtension.ensureObfuscations() {
        applicationVariants.configureEach variant@{
            assembleProvider.configure {
                doLast {
                    check(buildType.isDebuggable || buildType.isMinifyEnabled) {
                        "The build '$${this@variant.name}' is not minified. It must not be released!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app level build.gradle add this:

```kotlin
packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/"
            excludes += "okhttp3/"
            excludes += "kotlin/"
            excludes += "org/"
            excludes += ".properties"
            excludes += ".bin"
        }
    }
```

or change:

```kotlin
kotlin-parcelize
```

to:

```kotlin
kotlin-android-extensions
```

Comment: I can't say conclusively that your answer works because I worked around this issue by moving the plugins into a separate project and I published it to gradle plugins. Now when I copy them back to my project they work fine without even applying your answer. So I am not sure whats the reason for that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).